# Visual Studio 2015 C++ Create Definition without peek

Tags: visual-studio-2015

The new feature in Visual Studio 2015 which auto-generates a stub C++ definition based on the declaration in the .h file is great.  Except...  it opens a peek window which I do not want.  Can I prevent it from opening the peek window when I generate a function definition stub?

Comment: I really would like to know how to disable this if it is even possible. I could not find any helpful resources on the web for VS2015. Especially if I'm working with multiple displays where at least of of them has the .cpp file already opened it is a waste of time to always have to press escape to close the peek windows. Hope someone knows more about this topic.

Comment: I don't know exactly your VS version, but you can try to disable PEEK in: Options -> Productivity Power Tools -> Other Extentions; and also disable "Allow new files to be opened in preview tab" in Options -> Environment -> Tabs and Windows.

Comment: Nearly 2 years and a whole new VS version later, I still cannot remove this awful functionality.

Comment: 5 years later, still waiting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know if negative answer would count for you, but anyway:

A [quote from visualstudio.uservoice.com](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/11137503-consider-changing-the-behavior-of-the-create-defi):

> In Visual Studio 2015, Microsoft added the not so little light bulb that comes up every once and a while with suggestions. I would you the team to reconsider changing the behavior of the "create definition" so instead of opening this annoying inline editor at the bottom, it takes you directly to the source file. All the c++ productivity tools override this native behavior because it is so terrible and annoying.

And the official answer is

> Customizing the post-operation experience is on our backlog, and we hope to get to it soon!

This combined with the `under review` status of the suggestion makes me believe that currently there's no way of getting rid of inline editor popping up all the time.

On a rhetoric side note, I wonder why would they add a new feature without an option to disable it...

Comment: Anyone who's interested in this:  Please go that uservoice link above and vote for the issue!  That's (hopefully) the best way to increase attention on this one.